# for loop is not working inside of a windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute this in a Windows batch:

```dos
for /F %%A In ('PowerShell Get-Date -UFormat %V') do copy "D:\Versand\Test\OrdersOffers.xlsm" "D:\Versand\Test\OrdersOffersWeek%%A.xlsm"
```

But  nothing is happening. It works if I do it in CMD like this:

```dos
for /F %A In ('PowerShell Get-Date -UFormat %V') do copy "D:\Versand\Test\NL_OrdersOffers.xlsm" "D:\Versand\Test\NL_OrdersOffers%A.xlsm"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why not just use WMIC to get the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 -UFormat %V
```

becomes

```
 -UFormat %%V
```

because `%` is a special character that needs to be escaped by `%` itself

Comment: Using %%V is the solution. Thanks.